Choose which external display to create a window to using Android native activity c++
is there a way to iterate through connected external displays and choose which display I want to create a surface for with EGL? Ideally without having to use a JNI environment as I've tried that but it didn't work out because when I would try to create a surface on the provided ANativeWindow it would crash, and when I just did normal EGL creation (just getting the default) it worked fine.
Thanks!

There is no way to iterate displays, you can start a new activity with second display:https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/activity-launch, then init a new EGL context with-in this new activity window, that's the way to choose display for EGL.
